# I'm seeing inaccurate performance metrics when Lighthouse testing an Angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lighthouse

I'm running a Lighthouse test (version 2.7.0) on an Angular app (version 4.4.6) created with Angular CLI (1.4.8). It has been built with the --prod flag. Time to first meaningful paint is in 6+ seconds and time to first interactive is 11+ seconds. This seems extremely high compared to what I see compared when I stopwatch the page from a fresh browser window, which is roughly: time to first paint 1-2 seconds and time to first interactive 4 seconds.

Why is there such a large difference between what I measure myself and what Lighthouse reports?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: edited for clarity

Answer (score 1):

It tests with a slow 3G connection

These are the default settings on a lighthouse report

[image]